# Explicit forall on a type class function

Tags: haskell, typeclass, forall

Since ghc-8.0 we have a very nice extension called `TypeApplications`. Which allows us instead of:

```
λ> show (5 :: Int)
"5"
```

do so something like that:

```
λ> :set -XTypeApplications
λ> show @Int 5
"5"
```

Which is really cool. It becomes a bit more involved when we add more type variables, but there are rules that can be used to determine the exact order, and they are very well documented:

```
showFooBar :: (Show a, Show b) => a -> b -> String
showFooBar a b = show a ++ " and " ++ show b
```

So in the function above we would first supply `a` and then `b`:

```
λ> showFooBar @Int @Double 3 4
"3 and 4.0"
```

That's great, but what if I'd like to change the order? No problem there, we can use `ExplicitForAll` extension (or some other that imply it) to specify it:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExplicitForAll #-}

showFooBar :: forall b a . (Show a, Show b) => a -> b -> String
showFooBar a b = show a ++ " and " ++ show b
```

And now we reversed the order of types that we are going to apply:

```
λ> showFooBar @Int @Double 3 4
"3.0 and 4"
```

The problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to achieve the same affect for functions that are part of a type class. Consider this example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class (Show a, Show b) => FooBar a b where
  fooBarClassFunc :: a -> b -> String
```

I can't put `forall` on a function now (eg. `fooBarClassFunc :: forall a b . a -> b -> ..`, cause that changes the meaning of the function and obviously does not compile.

So, the question is, how do you change the order of type variables for the purpose of `TypeApplication` inside the type class methods?

*Edit*

Just in case, I have tried `InstanceSigs` extension, and it completely ignores the order of `forall` type variables as far as `TypeApplications` are concerned, which is a good thing, otherwise we would end up with behavior that is determined by the instance, rather than the class.

Comment: I don't think you can. But you could always make `fooBarClassFunc'` the method, and then define `fooBarClassFunc :: forall b a. ...` as a regular function.  Same effect for users, a little strange for instantiators...

Comment: @liqui Yes, of course. But I was more curious if it is possible on the typeclass itself, maybe some special syntax or something that I am not aware of. I don't particularly need to solve that either, this is just pure curiosity.

Comment: I naively believed that `QuantifiedConstraints` would allow to specify this as well, but it does not seem to allow anything like `class forall b a . (C a, C b) => K a b where`. Further, one might want the order to vary from method to method, for maximum generality.

Comment: Keep in mind you can still change parameter order in certain situations e.g. you can do `class X t where { func :: forall a b. t a -> t b -> t (a, b) }`. You just can't do it with `t`, which is the type on which the typeclass is defined. Not that that helps very much...

Answer (score 2):

> how do you change the order of type variables for the purpose of `TypeApplication` inside the type class methods?

@luqui's answer is good enough, I would think. But why not this:

```
class (Show b, Show a) => FooBar b a where
  fooBarClassFunc :: a -> b -> String
```

You only have one method, so the only consideration driving the order of parameters to the class is for the purpose of `TypeApplication` inside the methods.

If you have two or more methods for which you want the order of `TypeApplication` to be different (@chi's point, but why?), then for the other methods either luqui's suggestion, or (equivalently) an other class with a superclass constraint and a default implementation.

```
class (Show a, Show b, FooBar b a) => OtherFooBar a b where
  otherFooBarClassFunc :: a -> b -> String
  otherFooBarClassFunc = otherFooBarClassFunc'  -- default
instance {-# NOOVERLAPPABLE #-} OtherFooBar a b  where {}  -- take default
```

(Assuming `otherFooBarClassFunc'` is defined in the main class; and that's where the real instance definition goes on.)

There is a lot to be said for [one method per class](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/104232/an-alternative-history-of-haskell-being-lazy-without-class), of course.

`{-# NOOVERLAPPABLE #-}` wot we do not 'ave is my little in-joke.

Comment: There is no need to add another class in order to have a work around, adding a single function `otherFooBarClassFunc :: forall b a . FooBar a b => a -> b -> String`, where `otherFooBarClassFunc = fooBarClassFunc` would suffice. 
My question concerns the method attached to the class, not the things that are derived from it.